# Convert YYYY-MM-DD-HH-MM-SS to datetime sql server

Tags: t-sql, datetime, sql-server-2012

How to convert YYYY-MM-DD-HH-MM-SS to datetime ?

> Example: 2013-07-01-18-37-09

I am able to do below conversion

```
DECLARE @vardate varchar (50) = '2013-07-01-18-37-09'
SELECT CAST(Substring(@vardate,1,10) AS DATETIME)

SELECT CAST(Substring(REPLACE(@vardate,'-',':'),12,19) AS TIME)
```

but this won't work with time.. I searched on internet and I have seen that examples are related to YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try:

```
DECLARE @vardate varchar (50) = '2013-07-01-18-37-09'
SELECT CAST(LEFT(@varDate, 10) + ' ' + REPLACE(RIGHT(@vardate,8 ), '-', ':') AS DATETIME)
```

Comment: +1 so quick. I was trying to do with different substring functions.

Answer (score 2):

One of many reasons why you should seek to avoid passing dates around as anything other than datetime values. This is one way to do it:

```
DECLARE @vardate varchar (50) = '2013-07-01-18-37-09'

select CONVERT(datetime,STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(@vardate,11,1,'T'),14,1,':'),17,1,':'))
```